# Multithreaded Synchronised List<T>

Tags: c#, multithreading, list, generics

I have a requirement whereby I needed to store a simple cache of a list of items. I was using List< T > for this purpose, but we have now changed the design to accommodate multiple threads.

The architecture of the system is driven by events, therefore it's quite likely that a read and write operation could collide. Since the vast majority of access will be read-only I thought that the ReaderWriterLockSlim might be a good candidate. The cache only needs to be accurate at the point of reading for that moment in time.

I have written the code below and it seems to work ok, but are there some potential pain points?

**UPDATE: Whilst the code below does fix some synchronisation problems it's not 100% perfect. I have since decided to implement a much simpler class that doesn't expose all of the IList< T > operations and therefore makes it 'safer' to re-use.**

```
public class SynchronisedList<T> : IList<T>
{
    private ReaderWriterLockSlim cacheLock = new ReaderWriterLockSlim();
    private IList<T> innerCache = new List<T>();

    private U ReadReturn<U>(Func<U> function)
    {
        cacheLock.EnterReadLock();
        try { return function(); }
        finally { cacheLock.ExitReadLock(); }
    }

    private void Read(Action action)
    {
        cacheLock.EnterReadLock();
        try { action(); }
        finally { cacheLock.ExitReadLock(); }
    }

    private U WriteReturn<U>(Func<U> function)
    {
        cacheLock.EnterWriteLock();
        try { return function(); }
        finally { cacheLock.ExitWriteLock(); }
    }

    private void Write(Action action)
    {
        cacheLock.EnterWriteLock();
        try { action(); }
        finally { cacheLock.ExitWriteLock(); }
    }

    public T this[int index]
    {
        get { return ReadReturn(() => innerCache[index]); }
        set { Write(() => innerCache[index] = value); }
    }

    public int IndexOf(T item) { return ReadReturn(() => innerCache.IndexOf(item)); }
    public void Insert(int index, T item) { Write(() => innerCache.Insert(index, item)); }
    public void RemoveAt(int index) { Write(() => innerCache.RemoveAt(index)); }
    public void Add(T item) { Write(() => innerCache.Add(item)); }
    public void Clear() { Write(() => innerCache.Clear()); }
    public bool Contains(T item) { return ReadReturn(() => innerCache.Contains(item)); }
    public int Count { get { return ReadReturn(() => innerCache.Count); } }
    public bool IsReadOnly { get { return ReadReturn(() => innerCache.IsReadOnly); } }
    public void CopyTo(T[] array, int arrayIndex) { Read(() => innerCache.CopyTo(array, arrayIndex)); }
    public bool Remove(T item) { return WriteReturn(() => innerCache.Remove(item)); }
    public IEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator() { return ReadReturn(() => innerCache.GetEnumerator()); }
    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator() { return ReadReturn(() => (innerCache as IEnumerable).GetEnumerator()); }
}

internal class Program
{
    private static SynchronisedList<int> list = new SynchronisedList<int>();

    private static void Main()
    {          
        for (int i = 0; i < 500000; i++)
        {
            var index = i;
            ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem((state) =>
            {
                var threadNum = (int)state;
                if (threadNum % 10 == 0)
                {
                    list.Add(threadNum);
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(list.Count);
                }
            }, index);
        }
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

Comment: +1 since at first glance this seems a very useful class

Comment: Pretty dangerous class which fixes some synchronisation issues, but not all and gives the user a false sense of security.

Comment: I agree, I'll make sure I put a note in.

Comment: Good idea to keep the posting in case others decide they want to write one themselves! +1

Comment: You can solve all sync issues by using a scope. See my answer below, it's a variant of this class but solves all issues 100%.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Are you aware of the built-in [`SynchronizedCollection<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms668265.aspx) class?

It uses standard `Monitor`-based locking rather than `ReaderWriterLockSlim`. You'd need to profile to determine whether this makes a significant performance difference in your particular usage scenarios.

Answer (score 3):

There are a couple of thread issues here.

1.
I think the GetEnumerator functions exposes a thread issue here. They give away a reference to the innerCache that is not controlled by your locks.

Example where it may break down is if you have a thread doing a foreach over the list while another thread is removing or inserting elements.

The solution would be to copy the list and return an enumerator on that newly cloned list instead. The draw back would be memory issues if the list is long.

2.
The Contains() and IndexOf() functions are more or less useless unless you have another locking method outside of the synchronised list.

Example: Thread A gets index of object, Thread B inserts/removed/updates that object, Thread A index is now stale.

---

I don't think this is a great idea really with a fully synchronised list. Write a customised version instead with limited functionality.

If you only need a queue or stack, implement that one with only the two or three necessary methods that are fully synchronised. If you need more functionality than that, use a List and have the different threads do the synchronisation.

Comment: Ah, yes, good point - on that basis I'd imagine that LINQ queries on the IEnumerable<T> would also potentially cause issues?

Comment: anything or anyone using the enumerator outside of the locks would have race conditions.

Comment: @Mats: The enumerator will throw an exception if its underlying collection is altered mid-enumeration. So you don't need to worry about subtle race bugs, you do need to worry about show-stopping exceptions!

Answer (score 2):

This class solves all problems and makes your list 100% thread-safe.

Race conditions are avoided by using scopes that work just like transactions in databases.

**Client code**

```
List<T> unsafeList = ... 
var threadSafeList = new SyncronisedList(unsafeList);
using (threadSafeList.EnterReadScope()) {
   // all your sequential read operations are thread-safe
}
using (threadSafeList.EnterWriteScope()) {
   // all sequential read/write operations are thread-safe
}
```

**Class code**

```
public class SyncronisedList<T> : IList<T> {
    private readonly ReaderWriterLockSlim _threadLock;
    private readonly IList<T> _internalList;

    public SyncronisedList() : this(new List<T>()) {
    }

    public SyncronisedList(IList<T> internalList) {
        _internalList = internalList;
        _threadLock = new ReaderWriterLockSlim(LockRecursionPolicy.SupportsRecursion);
    }


    private U Read<U>(Func<U> function) {
        using (EnterReadScope())
            return function();
    }

    private void Read(Action action) {
        using (EnterReadScope())
            action();
    }

    private U Write<U>(Func<U> function) {
        using (EnterWriteScope())
            return function();
    }

    private void Write(Action action) {
        using (EnterWriteScope())
            action();
    }

    public IDisposable EnterReadScope() {
        return new Scope<T>(this, false);
    }

    public IDisposable EnterWriteScope() {
        return new Scope<T>(this, true);
    }

    public T this[int index] {
        get { return Read(() => _internalList[index]); }
        set { Write(() => _internalList[index] = value); }
    }

    public int IndexOf(T item) { return Read(() => _internalList.IndexOf(item)); }
    public void Insert(int index, T item) { Write(() => _internalList.Insert(index, item)); }
    public void RemoveAt(int index) { Write(() => _internalList.RemoveAt(index)); }
    public void Add(T item) { Write(() => _internalList.Add(item)); }
    public void Clear() { Write(() => _internalList.Clear()); }
    public bool Contains(T item) { return Read(() => _internalList.Contains(item)); }
    public int Count { get { return Read(() => _internalList.Count); } }
    public bool IsReadOnly { get { return Read(() => _internalList.IsReadOnly); } }
    public void CopyTo(T[] array, int arrayIndex) { Read(() => _internalList.CopyTo(array, arrayIndex)); }
    public bool Remove(T item) { return Write(() => _internalList.Remove(item)); }
    public IEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator() { return Read(() => _internalList.GetEnumerator()); }
    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator() { return Read(() => (_internalList as IEnumerable).GetEnumerator()); }


    private class Scope<U> : IDisposable {
        private readonly SyncronisedList<U> _owner;
        private readonly bool _write;

        internal Scope(SyncronisedList<U> owner, bool write) {
            _owner = owner;
            _write = write;
            if (_write)
                _owner._threadLock.EnterWriteLock();
            else
                _owner._threadLock.EnterReadLock();
        }

        public void Dispose() {
            if (_write)
                _owner._threadLock.ExitWriteLock();
            else
                _owner._threadLock.ExitReadLock();
        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your implementation is ok but you still have to care about synchronization problems :

given a list {"foo"}

```
int index = list.IndexOf("foo");
Console.WriteLine(list[index]);
```

Now, what if another thread does a list.Clear() between thoses two lines ?
You reader writer lock should be publicly accessible to handle thoses situations.
Of course, same for Enumerator,...

Comment: Yes, one caveat of the class is that the List<T> is only thread-safe for a single operation at a time. If you need to perform multiple operations you'll need to wrap them in their own external syncronisation method. I'd rather not expose the internal lock.

Comment: @Codebrain; but then there is no need for a synchronized list in the first place if you'd have to use an external lock to alter it. You should expose the internal lock to make sure that everyone uses the same synchronization mechanism.

Comment: See answer below for the simple solution.

Answer (score 0):

> Trying to make a list be all things to
>   all people and to be thread safe is
>   very hard.

I think you should look at the **operations** that **your application needs** and then design a class that exposes them in a thread safe way.    (A list it too low level)

Your design is not likely to be thread safe in real life, as the code calling the list is likely to combine operations in an unsafe way.

> Just exposing an Enumerator opens up a
>   lot of problem – what does it mean to
>   visit all items in a list while
>   another thread is changing the list?

Comment: It's not that hard. See my answer for solution.

Answer (score 0):

Certain operations on your list cannot be meaningfully thread-safe with regard to other operations.  For example, one thread is about to write to element 5, and another thread deletes element 3 such that what used to be element 5 gets moved to 4, and what used to be 6 gets moved to 5, the first thread will end up overwriting an element other than the one it was expecting.

It's certainly possible to have a useful thread-safe collection which exposes access by index, if one puts certain restrictions on its behavior, and has it implement a the same subset of `IList<T>` as would an array.

The most useful style of ThreadSafeList I can envision would support the following operations, in addition to those that would be available on an array-implemented `IList<T>`:

1. int Add(T item) -- Returns index of the new item

   AccessItem(index, ActionByRef proc) -- Call proc with list item as a `ref` parameter

   AccessItem(index, ActionByRef proc, ref XP1 xparam1) -- Call proc with list item as one `ref` parameter and `xparam1` as a second

   AccessItem(index, ActionByRef proc, ref XP1 xparam1, ref XP2 xparam2) -- As above, with another pass-through `ref` parameter

   Enumeration -- Returns the "live" state of each item that has been created prior to the start of enumeration.

The list would support adding items, but not inserting or deleting them.  Since the `Add` method would return the index of the newly-created item, whatever thread added an item would have exclusive control over it.  Further, the `AccessItem` primitives would allow two or more threads to use atomic primitives on list items in any way they saw fit (if `T` is a struct type with an exposed field, atomic primitives could also be used on those fields).

Such a type should not be built on `List<T>`, but instead on an `T[32][] arr`.  Start by setting `arr[0]` to a `T[16]`; if a 17th item is added, initialize `arr[1]` to a `T[32]`; if that gets full, initialize `arr[2]` to a `T[64]`, etc.  Any given index will always be represented by the same array element, even as the list expands, so accesses to an existing list element will not be affected by the expansion of the list.

An append-only list could be a useful thread-safe type, but I'm as yet unaware of any such types in any version of .net.

Comment: See my answer to solve these limitations. IList is perfectly fine for threadsafe use.

Comment: @HermanSchoenfeld: If two or more threads which *only* use methods in `IList<T>` call `Add` simultaneously, by what means could each thread receive ownership of a different item?  Once each thread has ownership of a different item, `IList<T>` would be adequate for allowing every thread to manipulate its own item without conflict without anyone having to worry about locks [although `List<T>` doesn't guarantee thread-safety in that scenario, a class implementing `IList<T>` could do so].  Your class has a number of severe disadvantages; most notably the fact that...

Comment: @HermanSchoenfeld: ...you allow control to enter user code while a lock is being held.  If that user code in Thread One gets blocked waiting on another lock, and that second lock can't be released until code in Thread Two acquires the lock which is being held on behalf of Thread One's user code, deadlock may result, leaving both threads and both collections permanently unusable.  An implementation using the pattern I described could be written without using any locks whatsoever (using `CompareExchange` spin locks instead).  If two threads simultaneously try to add an item that would require...

Comment: @HermanSchoenfeld: ...allocating a new array, both threads would allocate a new array and then use `CompareExchange` to try to store a reference to it.  Only thread's `CompareExchange` could succeed; all other threads would abandon their newly-allocated array and use the one whose reference was stored successfully.  Simultaneous requests could cause threads to do useless work that would end up getting abandoned, but no thread would ever have to wait for another thread to do anything.

Comment: You don't seem to understand the solution. ReadWriterLockSlim takes care of everything. Basically, read scopes can be applied simultaneously on the list (efficient), but any write scopes must be acquired exclusively (must wait until all the read or write scopes finish). Since a read lock cannot be upgraded to a write lock (will throw), deadlocks will never occur. I've used that pattern extensively in highly multithreaded production code and works like a charm, no issues.

Comment: your scenario about deadlock will never occur when N threads are fighting over 1 IList. But, if you have N threads fighting over M ILists then certainly you can get a deadlock. Example:thread 1 locks list 1 and then tries to lock list 2 whilst simultaneously thread 2 locks list 2 and then tries to lock list 1 which could result in a deadlock. However, this scenario occurs irrespective of the "solution" and has nothing to do with this question or design of IList (which can be threadsafe using scopes as shown above)

Comment: @HermanSchoenfeld: Your `EnterReadScope` and `EnterWriteScope` are public, are they not?  So who knows what other locks a client code might need to acquire, or what other things might cause client code to block, while within such a scoping block?

Comment: the question relates to an intrinsically thread-safe IList which is what my solution provides. If some thread locks the IList and decides to download 10 gig file from the net, then of course everything is blocked, but that's true of any thread-safety mechanism. That's not a thread safety issue but resource greediness issue. The point here is  that N threads can read/write to an IList in an 100% thread-safe manner, which CAN be done despite what most think.

Comment: @HermanSchoenfeld: With the approach I was suggesting, any number of threads could make use of a list simultaneously without access contention provided only that no two threads try to use the same item at the same time.  There's no danger of any thread holding locks for an excessively long time, because no thread would ever hold any locks.